# Update Multiple Columns using single case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have written sql that creates 4 columns: `Tier0`, `Tier1`, `Tier2` and `Weight`.

Weight is associated with the tiers such that

> when Tier0 = 'X' then weight = 0,
>   when Tier1 = 'X' then weight = 0.7, and 
>   when Tier2 = 'X' then weight = 1.

Right now my code for this portion of my SELECT statement is

```
CASE 
WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) > (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
THEN 'X' Else '' END AS Tier0,

CASE 
WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) = (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
THEN 'X' Else '' END AS Tier1,

CASE 
WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) < (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
THEN 'X' Else '' END AS Tier2,

CASE 
WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) > (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
THEN 0
WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) = (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
THEN 0.7
WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) < (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
THEN 1  
END AS Weight
```

Is there a way to contain that final long case staement in the first three case statements?

I would like to have one case statement for each Tier if possible, that both puts an X in the correct tier column, and also updates the weight column correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a derived table:

```
SELECT  Tier0,
        Tier1,
        Tier2,
        CASE 
            WHEN Tier0 = 'X' THEN 0
            WHEN Tier1 = 'X' THEN 0.7
            WHEN Tier2 = 'X' THEN 1
        END [Weight]
FROM (Your current query here) AS T;
```

Or a CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    Your current query here
)
SELECT  Tier0,
        Tier1,
        Tier2,
        CASE 
            WHEN Tier0 = 'X' THEN 0
            WHEN Tier1 = 'X' THEN 0.7
            WHEN Tier2 = 'X' THEN 1
        END [Weight]
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: I'd go ahead and make a CTE for the two average calculations (SUM() / Count()) but that's just my DRY ocd nature

Comment: @dotjoe yeah, I took the easy route

Answer (score 1):

What about this way?

```
CASE 
  WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) > (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
  THEN 0
  WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) = (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
  THEN 0.7 
  WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) < (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
  THEN 1  
END AS Weight
```

Comment: This is what I was going to say. There's no reason to keep nesting those cases.

Comment: This solution completely ignores the Tier columns.

Comment: @JohnS Leave those tier columns as is replace your code for the weight column.

Comment: You are correct though about the final case statement. I have edited my question to reflect this change.

Comment: Where do you use this CASE? Is select?

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the `Tier0`, `Tier1`, `Tier2` columns in a CTE, and then use that to calculate the `Weight` column:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    CASE 
    WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) > (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
    THEN 'X' Else '' END AS Tier0,

    CASE 
    WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) = (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
    THEN 'X' Else '' END AS Tier1,

    CASE 
    WHEN (SUM(vst.len_of_stay) / COUNT(vst.len_of_stay)) < (SUM(drg.drg_std_days_stay) / COUNT(drg.drg_std_days_stay))
    THEN 'X' Else '' END AS Tier2

  FROM ...)
SELECT Tier0, Tier1, Tier2,
       case when Tier0 = 'X' then 0
            when Tier1 = 'X' then 0.7
            when Tier2 = 'X' then 1
        end as weight
  from cte
```

At least this helps with the duplicating of the logic.